# Concatenation with Formating in bold and italics

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to write a VBA code for concatenation and also format one column values to Bold and other to bold and italics. Unable to get through it . Please help

```
=CONCATENATE([@[Job Title]],CHAR(10),[@[Business Segment]],CHAR(10),[@[US Pay Band]],CHAR(10)," ",CHAR(10),"Incumbent - ",[@Name],CHAR(10)," ",CHAR(10),"Hay Points - ",[@[Final Hay Points]],CHAR(10))
```

here Job title should be bold and name should be bold and Italics

Code from comments:

```
Sub bold()

Dim r As Range, c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set r = ws.Range("X:X")
For Each c In r 
    With c 
        .Font.bold = False 
        .Value = .Text 
        .Characters(1, InStr(.Text, vbLf) - 1).Font.bold = True
    End With
Next c 
...
End sub
```

Comment: Your tags don't really align with your question. Your formula looks like a excel format rather a VBA string. May help if you show some sample data with the expected output. You have also not listed a specific problem so it's not clear what you actually need help with. "Unable to get through it" tells us nothing really

Comment: I want Job Title as Bold and Name in bold and italics along with concatenation of cells but when I am doing the concatenation it is not working it goes in normal font

Comment: This is not possible if you are using a formula.

Comment: I wrote a VBA code which bolds the first line Job title but not the Incubment name
Sub bold()


Dim r As Range, c As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set r = ws.Range("X:X")
For Each c In r
    With c
        .Font.bold = False
        .Value = .Text
        .Characters(1, InStr(.Text, vbLf) - 1).Font.bold = True
    End With
    
Next c

Comment: You need to write the results of the Excel cell formula into the cell as a string.  You cannot differentially format the output of an excel cell formula.  It might be simpler to code if you do the concatenation within your VBA macro, rather than on the worksheet.